# Flutter - Removing system bar caused a white box to appear on the side

Tags: flutter

Before removing the system bar I had two boxes. After removing the system bar I gained a white bar on the side. I have no idea where it is coming from. I can take out the code that removes the system bar and the white bar disappears.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return Home();
}
}
class Home extends State{

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
    [
      SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
    ]
  );
 }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {


return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text('test'),
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      ),
    ],
  )
);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like the containers doesn't fill the full space because you have a column and divide the width by 0.5, I guess thats why you have this white space. The second thing I noticed is that for the width you divide the screen HEIGHT by 0.5 is that intented?

Comment: Nope, you are right. It is weird that it still worked before I took away the system bar

Answer (score 0):

Enviro Apps was right, My width was set wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).